# Why Smalltalk-80 MVC cannnot be applied to web development?

Tags: model-view-controller, web

I have read in some places that Smalltalk-80 original MVC is not applicable to web application development because (1) it was made to develop GUI components, not an entire application and (2) because model cannot communicate with view.

(1) is valid, but I do not understand (2). First, Smalltalk-80 MVC does not says that model communicates directly with view, it does so using events. Second, I have an assumption that only controller would be able to alter the model. Then, in a http request, controller layer alters model layer, which raise events which could be observed by view layer. The only diff to controller->model->controller->view (MVP - passive view) is how model notifies the view of its changes. Could someone clarify?

Comment: What makes you think this is the case? Rails and many other frameworks are built around the MVC model.

Comment: MVC represents a concept, there are several MVS implementations. I'm talking about the classical MVC implementation, developed for Smalltalk 76/80 by Trygve Reenskaug. afaik web frameworks do not use that.

Comment: OS X and iOS follow MVC very literally. Rails takes a much more casual approach, but the principle is the same: Division of responsibility, clear roles for code. I've seen people be very strict about separating concerns by using no-logic templates and such.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the most important point of MVC is responsibility separation. I'm now studying possible implementations and cons/pros of each and the question above arose.

Comment: This isn't really a question, then. What you need to do is actually try it out to see for yourself. If you've got any problems with your implementations, by all means post a question.

Comment: I *think* the issue is that, generally speaking, several controllers could update the same model and traditional web applications work with independent http requests. So, a view generated by a http request can only see changes in model caused by this request, not others requests running simultaneously in the web server. If that's the case, websockets API in HTML 5 could change this and support general model->view communication.

Comment: Think of the web server as a number of parallel worlds, each with their own MVC instances. There is no singular "server" much as we'd like to imagine it that way conceptually. It's an independent MVC per request, and in some frameworks, more than one when you account for sub-views and sub-controllers.

Comment: Summary: in traditional web development (request/response), model layer cannot update view layer because the model may be updated by any http request, a view is specific to a http request and http requests are isolated.

Comment: You're looking at this from an extremely narrow perspective. Just because the views are short-lived does not mean you can't use the MVC pattern.

Comment: As I already mentioned before, I know I can use MVC in web development, that's not my question at all. MVC patterns has several implementations, I'm talking specifically about the original MVC implementation, created by Trygve, implemented in Smalltalk-76/80 and defined in a paper named "
A Description of the Model-View-Controller User
Interface Paradigm in the Smalltalk-80 System". That implementation says that model layer should trigger model change events when updated, which are observable by the view layer, which would use this info to update itself.

Comment: If you're writing an academic paper, that's fine, but it's way beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. This isn't for computer science theory, it's for coding problems.